# how to make todolist remain after reload with local storage

Tags: javascript, html

i code this far but have no idea how to use localstorage so i dont have to lose my todolist in my browser when reload/refresh.

This is the code i have already set item to the local storage with savetodos function

```js
 var form =  document.querySelector('form') 
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul') 
    var button =  document.querySelector('#button'); 
    var input =    
    document.querySelector('#item'); 
    var clear =    
    document.querySelector('#clear');
    var savedToDos = [] 
    //this makes list item 
    var liMaker = text => { 
    var li = document.createElement('li');   
    li.textContent = text; 
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0]) 
    }    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault()
        liMaker(input.value)
        input.value = ''; }
    );
    
    clear.addEventListener('click', remove); 
    //function remove to remove list item
    function remove(){ 
        saveToDos(); 
        while (ul.firstChild) { 
            ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild); 
       }
    } 
    function saveToDos() { 
         var items = 
          ul.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) { 
                  savedToDos.push(
                  items[i].innerHTML); 
    }
              
    localStorage.setItem('savedValues', savedToDos); 
    }
```

```html
 <div class='container'> 
         <h1> New  todo list</h1> 
            <form>
                     <input type='text' id='item'     
                     required> 
               <ul id="myList"></ul> 
                <button id='button'>add</
                     button> </form> 
                <button id="clear">Clear</
                button> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it as follows:

- save input value to the localstorage when it's added
- populate the list on page load if there are items storage in the localstorage
- remove all items from the localstorage, when user click clear button

This is how it may look like:

```
<div className='container'>
    <h1> New todo list</h1>
    <form>
        <input type='text' id='item' required>
        <ul id="myList"></ul>
        <button id='button'>add</button>
    </form>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
<script>
  var form =  document.querySelector('form')
  var ul = document.querySelector('ul')
  var button =  document.querySelector('#button');
  var input = document.querySelector('#item');
  var clear = document.querySelector('#clear');
  var savedToDos = []
  //this makes list item
  var liMaker = text => {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = text;
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
  }
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    liMaker(input.value)
    saveToDo(input.value)
    input.value = '';
  });

  clear.addEventListener('click', remove);
  //function remove to remove list item
  function remove(){
    while (ul.firstChild) {
      ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
    }
    localStorage.removeItem('savedValues')
  }
  function saveToDo(item) {
    var storedItems = localStorage.getItem('savedValues');
    storedItems = storedItems ? JSON.parse(storedItems) : [];
    storedItems.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem('savedValues', JSON.stringify(storedItems))

  }
  // populate the list on page load from localStorage
  var storedItems = localStorage.getItem('savedValues');
  if (storedItems) {
    JSON.parse(storedItems).forEach(function(item) {
      liMaker(item)
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: can you please explain me saveToDo function in easy way i know ternary operation but cant understand your code.

Comment: Hi @daneillone. No problem. In `saveToDo` first we get `savedValues` from the local storage. If there are `savedValues` we parse them from a string to an array (local storage may only save strings, this is why we have to parse/stringify our array). If there are no `savedValues`, we just create a new empty array. Then we push the newly added item to the array, stringify the array back to the string and save it to the local storage.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong function saveTodo runs when we input value. and when function runs storedItems variable assign by ternary operation that check if there is savedValues in localstorage, if it is then parsed string object is saved to storedItems and reassign the localstorage. in this case item is not push inside storedItems cuz storedItems is not.empty array.   But when theres no savedvalues variable storedItems become array so item is push inside array and then save to localstorage. is this what its going inside function saveTodo.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Yes, `saveTodo` runs when input value is added. However we always push the new item to the array. The array may be empty (if no values were saved previously) or array may already have some items (if some input values were added previously). After that we anyway stringify the array and save it in the local storage.

Comment: how can the list show again when the page reloaded?